# DP states in SPOJ SERVICES

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am having a problem in the question [SERVICES](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SERVICE/) on SPOJ. I tried to solve it and came up with the following DP states [posofA][posofB][posofC][NextToMove]. But looking at the constraints, I think It will Give MLE. After trying for a day, I googled it and found blogs regarding a symmetry in the question. Despite my best efforts, I am unable to understand it. Can someone Please help and spare his time to help me. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of symmetry do you mean?

Comment: Hi @Codor , The symmetry mentioned in the blogs I found was that they mentioned the next town (acc to complaint) to be visited will come in DP states of the next level .For example if next town to be visited is 4 ,then 4 must be present in next DP State and same thing can be repeated for other also.But basic problem is with base case ...

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that you can drop **posOfC** and always denote **posOfC** by the last requested position. When you are processing a request , you can easily get the previous position. Now you have all the positions of the 3 partners. Send one of them to the new requested position checking that all of them will be in different location.

```cpp
int f(int pos,int a,int b)
{
        if(pos == req.sz)
                return 0;

        // last position
        int c = req[pos-1];

        // current position we are sending one of them
        int to = req[pos];

        if( dp[pos][a][b] != -1)
                return dp[pos][a][b];

        int ans = inf;
        // a goes to current request position
        if(b != c && b != to && c != to)
                ans = min(ans,f(pos+1,b,c) + cost[a][to]);
        // b goes to current request position
        if(a != c && a != to && c != to)
                ans = min(ans,f(pos+1,a,c) + cost[b][to]);
        // c goes to current request position
        if(a != b && a != to && b != to)
                ans = min(ans , f(pos+1,a,b) + cost[c][to]);

        return dp[pos][a][b] = ans;
}
```

First 3 elements of **req** will be **1,2,3** . Get the answer by calling `f(3,1,2)`.